# Could not load file or assembly 'XXXX.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, dll

I have an application that directly references a  dll file: `POSLink.dll`.

In order to get this to run on my local machine, I have to manually copy the following dlls to the output directory:  `libea32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`.

When I run the application on my local machine, it succeeds.

When I run the application on the target machine, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'POSLink.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>      at FileNotFoundExceptionExample.Program.Main(String[] args)

This is my SSCCE

```
using POSLink;
using System;

namespace FileNotFoundExceptionExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // this is stuff found in the POSLink namespace
            var commSetting = new CommSetting();
            commSetting.saveFile();

            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on POSLink.dll, but that wasn't very useful to me because there are 381 errors that show up, and they show up when I run it on the successful machine too.

How do I even begin troubleshooting this error?

---

When I run the Fuision log viewer and then run the application on the target machine, I get the following log:

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/19/2016 @ 2:18:48 PM) ***
>
> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
>   completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable
>   C:\Users\Omitted\Desktop\notfoundexceptionexample\debug  \FileNotFoundExceptionExample.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = POSLink, Version=1.0.5773.36725, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f3876d2e4b7eb819  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/Omitted/Desktop/notfoundexceptionexample/debug/ LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base =
>   NULL LOG: AppName = FileNotFoundExceptionExample.exe Calling assembly
>   : FileNotFoundExceptionExample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Omitted\Desktop\notfoundexceptionexample\debug\FileNotFoundExceptionExample.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: POSLink, Version=1.0.5773.36725,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f3876d2e4b7eb819 LOG: GAC Lookup was
>   unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Omitted/Desktop/notfoundexceptionexample/debug/POSLink.DLL.
>   LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file:
>   C:\Users\Omitted\Desktop\notfoundexceptionexample\debug\POSLink.dll
>   LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase. LOG: Assembly Name is:
>   POSLink, Version=1.0.5773.36725, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f3876d2e4b7eb819 LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns
>   assembly from
>   C:\Users\Omitted\Desktop\notfoundexceptionexample\debug\POSLink.dll.
>   LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.

Comment: See if the Fusion log viewer provides more information (be sure and run it as administrator). It should show you the specific paths that it probed to try and locate your DLL and its dependencies. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: where is your `using System.IO` also make sure in the reference node in the project that you have also added the necessary dll for `POSLink` manually

Comment: Did you find all DLL's in the exe directory or did you reference a DLL from the GAC?

Comment: if this is a 3rd party dll. .also make sure that the `CopyLocal` property is set to `true` then when you deploy the application make sure to copy all the .dll's in the bin folder to the target location along with it's corresponding .config.exe file and the actual .exe it's self.

Comment: @JeroenHeier They're in the exe directory

Comment: @MethodMan  `CopyLocal` is set to true.

Comment: I've edited my question to make clear a detail that might be important.  `libea32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` are not actually referenced by the project.  they're merely copied to the output directory.  (manually for the SSCCE, and with "copy if newer" for the actual project)

Comment: Have you checked the GAC on your local machine, and compared it to the GAC on the destination server? Use "gacutil -l" to get a list.

Comment: @EricJ. I've just added the fusion log

Comment: It looks like the primary DLL was located just fine. Are the other two DLLs unmanaged code that is being loaded from POSLink.dll? On both the working and non-working machine, are all three in the same directory? Are the permissions for accessing that directory the same from the perspective of the app loading the files? Permissions to the files themselves? Any chance you have the "untrusted" flag set on any of the files (the one you get when downloading files in IE from the internet)?

Comment: @DavidP  There are a lot of differences.  Anything specific I should be looking for?

Comment: @EricJ.  POSLink.dll isn't my code, but my current _assumption_ is that it is using something like `[DllImport]` to load the other 2 dlls.  All I know is that they need to be present in the output directory in order for the code to run on my local machine.  The bin/debug folder is copied directly from my local machine to the target machine, so the directory structure is the same

Comment: @EricJ. When I inspect the 3 dlls, it looks like everybody has full control, and I'm not seeing any "untrusted" flag set, but I don't exactly know where to look for it.

Comment: Maybe you have to register those 2 dll's. Any documentation on internet?

Comment: `Maybe you have to register those 2 dll's` Good point. See http://superuser.com/questions/298142/how-to-register-a-dll-file-in-windows-7

Comment: @EricJ.  When I do that, I get an error that says `the module "POSLink.dll""  failed to load.  Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.
  The specified module could not be found.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, as it turns out, there is a way to filter through all the unimportant errors that dependency walker tells you about.

1. obtain [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
2. obtain a diff tool.  I used [WinMerge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/).
3. Run Dependency walker on the dll in question on your good machine.  Copy the contents of the log window to a text file and save it.
4. Run Dependency walker on the dll in question on your bad machine.  Copy the contents of the log window to a text file and save it.
5. Use your diff tool to diff the two txt files.  In my case, The missing dll was in the top section(where the errors are) on the bad machine, ind in the bottom section(where the non-errors are) on the good machine.

Frankly  I'm embarrassed that I didn't try this before.  I had only assumed that the number of errors was the same based on how I assumed the log was laid out.

---

The log is the middle window that's selected in this screenshot.

[image: Dependency walker log]

As it turns out msvcr120.dll was indeed what was missing, and finding a suitable one, and dropping it into my output directory fixed the problem.

**NOTE:**  [msvcr120.dll is the Visual C++ 2013 Runtime](https://superuser.com/questions/827752/run-vcredist-x86-exe-missing-msvcr120-dll).  Instead of manually copying dlls around, the proper solution is installing [the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

[image: WinMerge]