# Azure Function: load unmanaged c++ dll from c#, Error: "Unable to load DLL or one of its dependencies"

Tags: azure-functions, dllimport

Azure Function use unmanaged DLLs, I got the error as follows:

"Unable to load DLL 'aa.dll' or one of its dependencies: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)
"

with the solution proposed by [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643543/include-c-c-unmanaged-code-dll-consumed-using-dllimport-in-azure-functions-p/57178302#57178302), I have successfully copied all my unmanaged DLLs to the bin folder in azure function.

In my case, I have two c++ DLLs **aa.dll** and **bb.dll**, **aa.dll** depends on **bb.dll**, I add **aa.dll** as follow to my code

```
[DllImport(@"aa.dll", EntryPoint = "StartCode", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    internal static extern string StartCode([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string strXmlImp, int nId);
```

it **works perfectly fine in my visual studio locally** (with azure function template), but after publish to the azure, I got the Error above. any idea? thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'XXXX.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466271/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-xxxx-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-speci)

Comment: i used dumpbin to analyse my aa.dll and bb.dll all the dependent assembly are located in system32 as follows: KERNEL32.dll
    USER32.dll
    GDI32.dll
    MSIMG32.dll
    WINSPOOL.DRV
    ADVAPI32.dll
    SHELL32.dll
    SHLWAPI.dll
    UxTheme.dll
    ole32.dll
    OLEAUT32.dll
    OLEACC.dll
    gdiplus.dll
    IMM32.dll
    WINMM.dll   i check enviroment all dll is on the azure funtion host

Comment: @DavidHeffernan excellent! in that case you could provide a helpful answer here for us !

Comment: I believe I have the exact same problem - did you ever find a solution?